# How to check if paypal.checkout.setup() has already been called?

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout, paypal

> Error: You are calling paypal.checkout.setup() more than once. This function can only be called once per page load. Any further calls will be ignored.

Are there any flags of getters in PayPal API to check it?

Similar [Paypal Express Checkout - You are calling paypal.checkout.setup() more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209304/paypal-express-checkout-you-are-calling-paypal-checkout-setup-more-than-once)